# Writing formulas inside LaTeX Table

Tags: tables

I have a simple table. I found that some of the Mathematical expressions cross the border of the cells. How to fix this problem?

I have the second question please which is also related to my table: I have merged five cells; how I can split it into two equal cells?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{First Table}
\label{my table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|c|l|}
\hline
Name & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{a}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{b} & c                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Test-1} & Test-2                                      \\ \hline
1    & aa                                   & bb                     & \multirow{5}{*}{same} & \multirow{2}{*}{222-a}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{333-a}} \\ \cline{1-3}
2    & cc                                   & dd                     &                       &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                       \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-6} 
3    & ee                                   & ff                     &                       & \multirow{3}{*}{222-b}      & \multirow{3}{*}{333-b}                      \\ \cline{1-3}
4    & $\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{M}\right)$ & gg                     &                       &                             &                                             \\ \cline{1-3}
5    & hh                                   & ii                     &                       &                             &                                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: Formulas inside a table]

Comment: please post a _complete_ MWE. i.e. including eveything that can be copied and compiled as is.

Comment: `I have the second question please which is also related to my table` it is best to post each question separately.

Comment: @Nasser I have provided the complete table, what should I provide more?

Comment: @sky-light We really need a full document, starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`, to see what you are loading, setting, _etc._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to writing mathematical formulas inside tables, your first impulse should be to treat it as if it were located in running, "inline" text. In particular, avoid `\frac` expressions and use in-fix "slash" notation instead.

Also, do try to give your tables a more "open" look. This is achieved easily simply by getting rid of all vertical lines; see below. Trust me, the vertical lines aren't needed, and they won't be missed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\centering
\caption{First Table}
\label{my table}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline
Name & a & b & c& Test-1 & Test-2 \\ 
\hline
1 & aa & bb& & \multirow{2}{*}{222-a} & \multirow{2}{*}{333-a} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
2 & cc & dd \\ 
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-6} 
3 & ee & ff & same \\ 
\cline{1-3}
4 & $\sin^{2^{\mathstrut}}(\pi/M)$ & gg & 
& 222-b & 333-b \\ 
\cline{1-3}
5 & hh & ii \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make latex tables less tight, either changing the value of `\arraystretch` or using the `\setcellgapes` command, from `makecell`, which adds a fixed height and depth to all cells in a table. Of course, `\multirow` then requires some small adjustment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array,multirow, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{cellspace} %
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{First Table}
  \label{my table}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|c|l|}
    \hline
    Name & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{b} & c & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Test-1} & Test-2 \\ \hline
    1 & aa & bb & \multirow{5}{*}{same} & \multirow{2}{*}{222-a} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{333-a}} \\ \cline{1-3}
    2 & cc & dd & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-6}
    3 & ee & ff & & \multirow{3}{*}{222-b} & \multirow{3}{*}{333-b} \\ \cline{1-3}
    4 & $\sin^{2}\left(\frac{π}{M}\right)$ & gg & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
    5 & hh & ii & & & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{First Table}
  \label{my table}\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|c|l|}
    \hline
    Name & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{b} & c & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Test-1} & Test-2 \\ \hline
    1 & aa & bb & \multirow{5}{*}[-0.72ex]{same} & \multirow{2}{*}{222-a} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{333-a}} \\ \cline{1-3}
    2 & cc & dd & & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-6}
    3 & ee & ff & & \multirow{3}{*}[-.75ex]{222-b} & \multirow{3}{*}[-.75ex]{333-b} \\ \cline{1-3}
    4 & $\sin^{2}\left(\frac{π}{M}\right)$ & gg & & & \\ \cline{1-3}
    5 & hh & ii & & & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of writing `\multirow{5}{*}{same}` or `\multirow{5}{*}[-0.72ex]{same}` for the material in column "c", wouldn't it be easier to just write "same" in row "3"/column "c"?

Comment: @Mico: I thought of it, but decided (in a silly way?) to fit the O.P.'s choice. But you're perfectly right! A last tghought: would that mean we should use `\multirow{n}` only for even `n`s?

Comment: As long as the rows are of roughly equal height -- as is the case here -- I'd agree with the "last thought". In fact, it's the reason why I have only one pair of `\multirow` statements in my parallel answer. :-)